# moving sprites in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, loops

I am making a game which requires the sprites to move towards the bottom of the screen. You can imagine it a bit like a rhythm game(guitar hero). However, I am having problems as the sprites are not moving at all even if the loop seems to work fine.

The GamePanel-

```
package com.jollygent.tapthepointer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView{

SurfaceHolder holder;
GameLoopThread loop;
GamePanel game = this;
Random rand;
int y;
//ArrayList<Pointers> pointers = new ArrayList<Pointers>();
Pointers pointers;

public GamePanel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    holder = getHolder();
    loop = new GameLoopThread(this);
    rand = new Random();
    pointers = new Pointers(rand.nextInt(4)+1,getWidth()/2,0,this); 
    //placeholder 


    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loop.setRunning(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            loop = new GameLoopThread(game);

            if(!loop.isRunning()){
                loop.setRunning(true);
                loop.start();
            }
            else{
                loop.setPause(false);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stubn

        }
    });



}

public GameLoopThread getLoop(){
    return loop;
}

public void update(){



}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){

    pointers.draw(canvas);


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    canvas.drawLine(0,getHeight()/2 + 50,getWidth(),getHeight()/2 + 50, paint);


  }

}
```

The Pointer class

```
package com.jollygent.tapthepointer;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;

public class Pointers {

GamePanel game;
private int x,y;
Bitmap pointer;
Bitmap rotated_pointer;
Matrix matrix;

public Pointers(int type,int x,int y,GamePanel game){

    this.game = game;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    pointer = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(game.getResources(),R.drawable.pointer_xx);
    matrix = new Matrix();

    switch(type){


    //points right
    case 1:
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        break;
    //points left
    case 2:
        matrix.postRotate(-90);
        break;
    //points up
    case 3:
        rotated_pointer = pointer;
        break;
    //points down
    case 4:
        matrix.postRotate(180);
        break;

    }

    rotated_pointer =   Bitmap.createBitmap(pointer,0,0,pointer.getHeight(),pointer.getWidth(), matrix,true);
}


public void update(){

    /*if(y < game.getHeight()){
        y += pointer.getHeight();
    }*/

}

public int getHeight(){
    return pointer.getHeight();
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas){

    y++;//placeholder movement to see if the sprite actually moves. It doesn't.
    canvas.drawBitmap(rotated_pointer,x,y,null);

 }

}
```

Finally, I think it's necessary to post the GameLoopThread-

```
package com.jollygent.tapthepointer;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

public class GameLoopThread extends Thread{

GamePanel game;
boolean running  = false;
boolean paused = false;
Canvas canvas;
static final int FPS = 10;



public GameLoopThread(GamePanel game){
    this.game = game;
}

public boolean isRunning(){
    return running;
}

public void setRunning(boolean b){
    this.running = b;
}

public void setPause(boolean b){
    this.paused = b;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long beginTime;
    long ticks = 1000/FPS;
    long sleepTime;


    while(running){


       if(!paused){ 
           beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
           canvas = null;
           try{
               canvas = game.holder.lockCanvas();
               synchronized(game.getHolder()){
                   game.draw(canvas);
               }
           }finally{
               if(canvas != null){
                   game.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
               }
           }

           sleepTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime)/ticks;

           try{
               if(sleepTime > 0) 
                   Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
               else
                   Thread.sleep(10);

           }catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
    }       

}




    }
```

I'm probably making a very stupid mistake, but no matter how much I scan into the code and change around few bits I can't seem to figure out how exactly to move the sprite. Also, how can I make it so the sprite is centered exactly in any device?

Thank you.

EDIT:

```
package com.jollygent.tapthepointer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

GamePanel game;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    game = new GamePanel(this);
    setContentView(game);

}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    game.getLoop().setPaused(true);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){ 
    super.onResume();
    game.getLoop().setPaused(false);

  }
}
```

The problem is that the loop only runs once and once only. Perhaps the GameActivity is the problem?

Comment: Are you actually moving any of the objects? I see that your `update()` method is empty. Did you intent to update your sprites' coordinates there?

Comment: yes, but putting for example pointers.increaseY() in gamepanel class or just simply y++ in the actual pointers class does not seem to work. That's why in pointers.draw(canvas) I put y++

Comment: please help. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Ok so you indicated that the loop only runs once, so you mean the `while(running)` loop you have in `GameLoopThread` only runs once? So far the code doesn't look like anything very bad is standing out. You should try and debug the reason behind why the loop is only running once because that seems to be a considerable problem.